# Can "drop her" mean "stop nagging her"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

By read this headline:

> "Liz Cheney’s consultants are given ultimatum: drop her, or be dropped"

I get 'drop' means *to abandon*, but as mind learning English I wondered if in a different context "drop her" would mean: "stop nagging her" like: "drop her, you're annoying her"? or any other context. So can 'drop' mean *leave her alone*?

Comment: I would point out that, regardless of whether it *can* mean that, in the headline you quoted it *does not* mean that.

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary to see how many meanings "drop" can have?

Answer (score 12):

"Drop" in the sense of "stop nagging" is more often paired with "it." I tell my dog "drop it" when I want her to release something she has in her mouth. If someone is pestering you and you said "drop it," the antecedent to "it" would be "the topic."

But I think the meaning of "drop" intended in the quote is what LawrenceC referenced, "break your association with" someone. The ultimatum expands to: "Either you stop doing business with Liz Cheney, or we [who are also your clients] will stop doing business with you."

Answer (score 2):

*Drop X* can mean "remove X from your task list."

So if the consultants have a list of people they need to nag daily or some other interval, "drop X" can mean to stop nagging them in that context.